# How to avoid copy of hidden file only at root with lftp?

Tags: lftp

I'm using lftp to backup some websites on a local computer.

There is many folder at root (one of these folder is public_html/) of the website. But, I want that lftp copy only the public_html/ folder and its content.

None of the other folders at root must be copied. Only public_html/.

How to use the --exclude= ????

Thanks

Comment: May be I should exclude all an after include only the public_html/ directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will do the job :
--exclude='.*' --exclude='.*/' --include='public_html/'

Answer (score 0):

To mirror a single folder, just specify it as the source:

```
mirror public_html
```